# php remove words from a string

Tags: php

Suppose i have the following strin

```
assigned order 1234
```

I would like to remove the words

```
assigned order
```

So my final output should be

```
1234
```

How do i go about this in php

SO something like

```
$string = "assigned order 1234";
```

$newstring = //stuck here

NOte that the value 1234 can also be 767as33 BUT THE PART assigned order always remains constant

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Tried [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)? This is something you easily could have googled. You should _always_ do extensive research and try something before you post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would break into array of word, than take the last array item.

$words = explode(' ', $text);
$orderno = end($words);

Answer (score 0):

You should do a simple substring replacement:

```
$string = "assigned order 1234";
$newstring = substr_replace($string, '', 0, 15);//15 is the number of characters in 'assigned order '

echo 'new string: ' . $newstring;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php